# how to do reindexing and cache clear with external file

Tags: magento2, cache, reindex

I m seeking code for reindexing and cache clear via external `php` file in `Magento 2`. but I'm not succeeding.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?php
    $command = 'php /path-to-magento-root-directory/bin/magento cache:clean && php /path-to-magento-root-directory/bin/magento indexer:reindex';
    echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
?>
```

It will do the task and will produce this output:

```
Cleaned cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
eav
customer_notification
full_page
config_integration
config_integration_api
translate
config_webservice
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:08
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:07
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:19
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

Comment: it is working fine but after running this file i have to clear my browser cookie but why?

Comment: It doesn't need to clear browser cookie. It just works in the same manner as the running the commands in shell.

Comment: I have tried this and found no such problem on my end.

Comment: ok it is working fine now..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is in magento root folder. Add the below code.

```
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

//for reindex.
$IndexerFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory');
$CollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory');

$indexerCollection = $CollectionFactory->create();
   $ids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
   $idx = $IndexerFactory->create()->load($id);
   $idx->reindexAll($id); // this reindexes all
   //$idx->reindexRow($id); // or you can use reindexRow according to your need
}

// for clear cache 
$cacheTypeList = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
$cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
$types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

Comment: Ok let me try with this code..

Comment: Your code is not working properly. it is goes infinite after doing this. when i try to open anything. it gives me error like this.`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at`

Answer (score 1):

Backticks can be used in PHP to execute shell commands:

```
<?php

`/var/www/magento2/bin/magento cache:flush && /var/www/magento2/bin/magento indexer:reindex`;
```

You can prepend it with `echo` to show the output in your browser.

However, note that executing shell scripts in your php scripts with either backticks, `exec()` or `shell_exec()` is considered bad practice.